# How to add gridview with Lazy Loading and slideshow in one page flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to make page with gridview.builder and slideshow at top page and add to gridview lasy loading. I add every thing but lasy loading not work this is my code:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<String> images = [
    'https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300',
    'https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/300',
    'https://picsum.photos/id/3/200/300',
  ];

  List<dynamic> data = [];

  bool isLoading = false;

  int page = 1;

  final int perPage = 10;

  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_page=$page&_limit=$perPage'));

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
      page++;
      data.addAll(jsonDecode(response.body));
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    fetchData();

    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        fetchData();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Demo'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 200,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: images.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Image.network(images[index]);
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: GridView.builder(
              controller: _scrollController,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: data.length,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                childAspectRatio: 0.75,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Image.network(
                          data[index]['thumbnailUrl'],
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 8),
                      Text(
                        data[index]['title'],
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                        maxLines: 2,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 8),
                      Text(
                        'ID: ${data[index]['id']}',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: isLoading ? 16 : 0),
          Center(
            child: isLoading
                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                : SizedBox(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note, before adding the slide show , it was working, but after adding it, it is no longer working. No error is displayed in the code.
Any one solve to this problem?

Comment: where is your slideShow? Plus i think condition would be  ( _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent == _scrollController.offset )

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems to be missing the lazy loading functionality.
Update your fetchData function to fetch data based on the current page value and the per-page limit. Currently, you are fetching data from a static URL, but you can modify it to fetch data from an API or any other data source that supports pagination.
Modify your initState method to fetch the initial data when the page loads:
example:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  fetchData();
}
```